# Trying to figure out how to find the max count

Tags: mysql, sql

> Which team has the most number of members on their roster?

Okay so below is the code that I have input currently. It returns all the teams as well as how many people are on each team. I am not sure how to code it to only display the team with the most members as when I try to use a max function and a count function I get an error.

```
SELECT Team_Name, COUNT(Member.Student_ID_Num) 
FROM Teams 
JOIN Member ON Teams.Team_Number = Member.Team_Number 
GROUP BY Team_Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then the `ROW_NUMBER` function comes in handy here:

```
SELECT Team_Name, cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT t.Team_Name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM Teams t
    INNER JOIN Member m
        ON t.Team_Number = m.Team_Number
    GROUP BY t.Team_Name
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you instead want all ties for the highest count, should two or more teams be tied, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`.

If you have to do this the old fashioned way, without `LIMIT` or `ROW_NUMBER`, then get ready for a really ugly query:

```
SELECT
    t.Team_Name,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Teams t
INNER JOIN Member m
    ON t.Team_Number = m.Team_Number
GROUP BY t.Team_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                                         FROM Teams t
                                         INNER JOIN Member m
                                             ON t.Team_Number = m.Team_Number
                                         GROUP BY t.Team_Name) t );
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try below - using limit and order by desc

```
Select Team_Name, count(Member.Student_ID_Num) as cnt
from Teams join Member on Teams.Team_Number = Member.Team_Number 
group by Team_Name
order by cnt desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are not allowed to use "limit" because I did already try that

Comment: Why aren't you "allowed" to use `LIMIT`?

Comment: Its for a homework assignment, but we are not allowed to use "limit" as our teacher considers it a short cut that although will provide the correct answer it is not the way she wants it done.

Comment: I'm upvoting this, because in many circumstances this is arguably the best answer for MySQL (though this particular OP can't use it due to assignment restrictions).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the team with the highest member count, we need no join (unless we also want to show the member count). One thing to keep in mind that there may be multiple teams sharing the same maximum member count.

The old fashioned way in standard SQL, before there was any limit clause (`FETCH FIRST ROWS` in standard SQL) was this:

1. Count members per team number.
2. Get the maximum count.
3. Get the team number(s) with this maximum count.
4. Get the team(s) for these team numbers.

The query:

```
select *
from teams
where team_number in
(
  select team_number
  from member
  group by team_number
  having count(*) =
  (
    select max(cnt) as max_cnt
    from
    (
      select count(*) as cnt
      from member
      group by team_number
    ) counted
  )
);
```

As of MySQL 8 we would rather use a wnindow function, however:

```
select *
from teams
where (team_number, 1) in
(
  select team_number, rank() over (order by count(*) desc)
  from member
  group by team_number
);
```